# Deleting Original Line from the output file

Tags: c#

I want to remove `tempstring` lines from the output.txt file

```
File.Copy(words, Npath);
StreamReader temp = new StreamReader(Npath, Encoding.UTF8);
string tempstring = temp.ReadToEnd();
string[] temp3 = tempstring.Split(',');
temp.Close();

StreamWriter sW = File.AppendText(Npath);
string remove = tempstring.Replace(tempstring," ");
foreach (string item in temp3)
{
    string str = item.TrimStart().TrimEnd();
    string newStr = "<addr-line>" + str + "</addr-line>";
    sW.WriteLine(newStr);
}
sW.Close();
```

The output .txt file shows

> > **Marko Kostic, Faculty of Technical Sciences, University of Novi Sad,
> >     Trg D. Obradovica 6, 21125 Novi Sad, Serbia**

```
<addr-line>Marko Kostic</addr-line>
<addr-line>Faculty of Technical Sciences</addr-line>
<addr-line>University of Novi Sad</addr-line>
<addr-line>Trg D. Obradovica 6</addr-line>
<addr-line>21125 Novi Sad</addr-line>
<addr-line>Serbia</addr-line>
```

I want to remove the Bold Paragraph, which in code is `tempstring` from the output file

Any suggestions?

Comment: Show your input and output files content.

Comment: "Marko Kostic, Faculty of Technical Sciences, University of Novi Sad,
Trg D. Obradovica 6, 21125 Novi Sad, Serbia" This my Input file text the output i wrote it before

Comment: The problem in this code could be easily identified if you start the debugger, proceed step by step and check the values of the variables involved.

Comment: string text=text.Replace("BoldedText", string.Empty); will this do? By the way, your file io related lines seem irrelevant with your problem, it may baffle the readers.

Comment: i did it Steve and `string remove` actually return space but in the output i cant see any thing removed

Answer (score 0):

why are using append?

```
//StreamWriter sW = File.AppendText(Npath);
StreamWriter sW = new StreamWriter(Npath);
```

this will remove the old content (which you read before) and set the new one.

Comment: mmmmmmm suggest me another way Star, Notice Star am not professional in C# so if you can help me i will be grateful

Comment: you need to use append for some reasons !! my suggestion for now is go edit your question and say that you need to use append.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
StreamWriter sW = File.AppendText(Npath);
```

with

```
StreamWriter sW = new StreamWriter(Npath, false);
```

Since, you want to overwrite text in your file so instead of opening the file in append mode you should create a new `StreamWriter` and pass `false` parameter which will set false value for `append` option.